# Excel data validation based on two cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want excel to restrict data entry in **Column C** if following conditions are True:-

1. **if Col A = "OPS" --- Restrict data entry in Col C**
2. **If Col B = "Awaited" --- Restrict data entry in Col C**

I tried this formula in Custom Validation:

- **=AND(A2<>"OPS", B2<>"Awaited")** but its not working.

I want excel to allow data entry in **Column C** only if **Column A** contains **"NPS"** and **Column B** contains **some number(or text other than "Awaited")**
Please Help.
I have uploaded an image file...[Spanshot_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkoCR.jpg)

**Thanks for your help in advance...**

Comment: You are saying `Column A` but in formula `G2` what up???

Comment: Your condition 1 is further complicated in the text below it ("_I want excel to allow data entry in Column C only if Column A contains "NPS"_").  This correction will fix the validation: `=AND(G2="NPS", I2<>"Awaited")`

Comment: @harun24hr, now corrected!

Answer (score 1):

In Data validation remove tick from "Ignore blank", then if column B is blank, the formla won't allow to edit column C. I hope this helped.
Write this into the data validation in the first cell

```
=AND(A1="*NPS*",B1<>"Awaited")
```

, and just extend down.

Comment: "ignore blank" is irrelevant, but your conditional validation corrects OP's mistake.

Comment: Thanks Grosi, your suggested formula restricts me from entering data in Col "C" only where Col "B" contains "Awaited", but for Col "A" = "OPS", I am allowed to enter data..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula in column C.

```
=IF(AND(A1="NPS",B1<>"Awaited"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: "IF" is redundant. The "AND" function will produce valid boolean results.

Comment: Yes thats true but for better understanding `TRUE` `FALSE` is helpfull who are not so familiar with logics.