# Data validation to restrict possible cell values based on filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of values: capabilities, domains, sub-domains and descriptions (B2:E322).

I would like to perform data validation similar to that conducted by the standard filter selection - if I filtered the table for one of the capabilities, only the mapped domains are now available to me in the table. My ask specifically:

- I select a domain in Sheet 2 cell B2 (I have already restricted possible entries using data validation). e.g, 'X'.
- The only options available as a drop down for selection in C2 are domains whose capability is the selected one in B2. In this example, that would be 1 and 3.
- Repeated process for sub-subdomains and the value in C2 - if 1 is the selected domain, only 'red' would be available as a sub-domain choice in d2.

Table for reference:

| Capability | Domain | Sub-domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | Red |
| X | 3 | Green |
| Y | 7 | Yellow |
| Z | 5 | Blue |
| Z | 11 | Purple |

I have attempted to mash the formula shown in this answer ([Excel data validation based on two cell values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695307/excel-data-validation-based-on-two-cell-values)) with little success, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

[image]

---

**Helpers:**

Formula in `I2`:

```
=FILTER(B2:B6,A2:A6=F2,"")
```

Formula in `J2`:

```
=FILTER(C2:C6,(A2:A6=F2)*(B2:B6=F3),"")
```

---

**Lists:**

Data - List reference in `F2`:

```
=$A$2:$A$6
```

Data - List reference in `F3`:

```
=I2#
```

Data - List reference in `F4`:

```
=J2#
```